# can't find where django endpoint redirects to

Tags: python, django

tldr; - There is a microsoft github django project that I am trying to understand. I am trying to figure out where there `/redirect` endpoint's code is or leads to **for there first project called `1-authentication`**. Here is the link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial

I am very new to django and I am porting over a flask webapp I made to django. The specific endpoint I am trying to find is the `/redirect` endpoint's code.

**The specific problem** I am trying to find out where Microsoft/Azure places you once you completed the sign-in process.

I want to find out where this endpoint's code is so I can force it to redirect to an endpoint called `/closeauth`. `/closeauth` is an html file I made that will do a try block to see if you are using outlook, if you are not using outlook, but are using the web, it will kick you out to the normal `/` home endpoint. However, if you are using outlook, it will send a message back to the parent webpage to let outlook know that authenciation is succesful, then the parent webpage will try to go to `/`.

To understand what I mean, here is an example in flask with the
app.config file and the redirect endpoint which is the exact code I am looking for django:

app_config.py:

```
import os
REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"
```

app.py for flask example

```
@app.route(app_config.REDIRECT_PATH)
def authorized():
    try:
        cache = _load_cache()
        result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(
            session.get("flow", {}), request.args)
        if "error" in result:
            return render_template("auth_error.html", result=result)
        session["user"] = result.get("id_token_claims")
        _save_cache(cache)
    except ValueError:  # Usually caused by CSRF
        pass  # Simply ignore them
    return redirect(url_for("closeauth"))
```

However I can't find where this `/redirect` is in django.

**to test the code I am talking about use this microsoft github link** https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial
**I am using the first project `1-authentication` and changed the code for that. But I still can't figure out where the redirect code is to route the redirect somewhere else AFTER it was authenticated with Microsoft.**

It comes with a read me which says:

> 1. In the app's `Sample/urls.py` module, the necessary MSAL endpoints are hooked up:

````
```python
from ms_identity_web.django.msal_views_and_urls import MsalViews
...    
msal_urls = MsalViews(settings.MS_IDENTITY_WEB).url_patterns()
...
path(f'{settings.AAD_CONFIG.django.auth_endpoints.prefix}/', include(msal_urls)),
```
````

> - The above code sets up middlwares and hooks up all necessary endpoints for the authentication process into your Django app under a route prefix (`/auth` by default). For example, the redirect endpoint is found at `/auth/redirect`.
> - When a user navigates to `/auth/sign_in` and completes a sign-in attempt, the resulting identity data is put into the session, which can be accessed through the request object at `request.identity_context_data`.

but I can't find out where the `/auth/redirect` code is to change the ending point from `/` to `/closeauth`

I also checked the file of `msal_views_and_urls.py` and didn't see where the `/auth/redirect` goes to.

```
try:
    from django.urls import path
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from django.urls import reverse
except:
    pass
import logging

class MsalViews:
    def __init__(self, ms_identity_web):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('MsalViewsLogger')
        self.ms_identity_web = ms_identity_web
        self.prefix = self.ms_identity_web.aad_config.django.auth_endpoints.prefix + "/"
        self.endpoints = self.ms_identity_web.aad_config.django.auth_endpoints

    def url_patterns(self):
        return [
            path(self.endpoints.sign_in, self.sign_in, name=self.endpoints.sign_in),
            path(self.endpoints.edit_profile, self.edit_profile, name=self.endpoints.edit_profile),
            path(self.endpoints.redirect, self.aad_redirect, name=self.endpoints.redirect),
            path(self.endpoints.sign_out, self.sign_out, name=self.endpoints.sign_out),
            path(self.endpoints.post_sign_out, self.post_sign_out, name=self.endpoints.post_sign_out),
        ]

    def sign_in(self, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{self.prefix}{self.endpoints.sign_in}: request received. will redirect browser to login")
        auth_url = self.ms_identity_web.get_auth_url(redirect_uri=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(self.endpoints.redirect)))
        return redirect(auth_url)

    def edit_profile(self, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{self.prefix}{self.endpoints.edit_profile}: request received. will redirect browser to edit profile")
        auth_url = self.ms_identity_web.get_auth_url(
                redirect_uri=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(self.endpoints.redirect)),
                b2c_policy=self.ms_identity_web.aad_config.b2c.profile)
        return redirect(auth_url)

    def aad_redirect(self, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{self.prefix}{self.endpoints.redirect}: request received. will process params")
        return self.ms_identity_web.process_auth_redirect(
            redirect_uri=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(self.endpoints.redirect)),
            afterwards_go_to_url=reverse('index'))

    def sign_out(self, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{self.prefix}{self.endpoints.sign_out}: signing out username: {request.identity_context_data.username}")
        return self.ms_identity_web.sign_out(request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(self.endpoints.post_sign_out)))    # send the user to Azure AD logout endpoint

    def post_sign_out(self, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{self.prefix}{self.endpoints.post_sign_out}: clearing session for username: {request.identity_context_data.username}")
        self.ms_identity_web.remove_user(request.identity_context_data.username)  # remove user auth from session on successful logout
        return redirect(reverse('index'))                   # take us back to the home page
```

**Note:** I have a very weird feeling no one knows what I am talking about. If that is the case, I will get rid of the MS authentication that came with the django test app from here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial and instead use the msal library that was used in flask.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out where the redirect's code is but I hope that someone else may add there input as I was just guessing and got lucky I think.

In the readme it said:

> In the app's `Sample/urls.py` module, the necessary MSAL endpoints are >hooked up:
>
> ```py
> from ms_identity_web.django.msal_views_and_urls import MsalViews
> ...    
> msal_urls = MsalViews(settings.MS_IDENTITY_WEB).url_patterns()
> ...
> path(f'{settings.AAD_CONFIG.django.auth_endpoints.prefix}/', >include(msal_urls)),
> ```

I right clicked on `.url_patterns()` from the `msal_urls` variable that was located in the `urls.py` file. It brought me to the `msal_views_and_urls.py` file that was installed in my python. From there I saw a function within a class that seemed to be what I was looking for:

```
def aad_redirect(self, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{self.prefix}{self.endpoints.redirect}: request received. will process params")
        return self.ms_identity_web.process_auth_redirect(
            redirect_uri=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(self.endpoints.redirect)),
            afterwards_go_to_url=reverse('index'))
```

I changed `afterwards_go_to_url=reverse('index'))`  to `afterwards_go_to_url=reverse('closeauth'))` and it worked locally.

However I assume that wont work for deployment. I may have to test a venv and see if I can control that file.

If anyone has any more detail on this let me know.